# How to build a web server in GCP with the Internal IP restriction

Tags: web, google-cloud-platform, server, ip, cloud

I am planning to build a back office Machine Learning Model Performance Monitoring Dashboard using Python Flask in **GCP(Google Cloud Platform)** with Internal (Private) IP restriction. However, when I deploy this into QV environment, the only approach I know to access the webpages is by using IAP, which is not convenient for other non-technical users.

Does anyone know what is the best practice to build a webserver for an enterprise internal use in GCP?

Comment: 1) Private means private. That means you need to deploy a VPN if you do not want to use TCP tunneling (IAP). 2) What is QV environment?

Comment: If i had to guess, I'd say 'quality verification'?

Comment: Hi all , (1) yes, QV means Quality Verification Environment, a kind of testing environment. (2) For VPN, we exactly use company's VPN, by which we can access GCP services, but I actually have no ideas using VPN to access the web pages I built in Private IP environment. Any videos or documents can be very beneficial and helpful~ Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You need to have several condition to access to your private IP from your company:

- The users need to be on the entreprise network
- The entreprise network needs to be connected to your VPC (VPN, interconnect, maybe peering on GCP)
- The entreprise router/firewall must route the traffic to the Google Cloud reserved ranges through the VPN/interconnect. The firewall must allow the correct traffic (HTTP, HTTPS?) to GCP
- If you use domain name in your QV environment, you need to register your VM private IP in your entreprise DNS to allow the users' browser to resolve the QV domain name and use the private IP which will be routed through the VPN/interconnect to Google Cloud.